# What's the difference between "either" and "neither"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, negation

What's the difference between *either* and *neither*?
Can you provide me some examples?

Comment: While it's always appreciated to post such questions here, you may also want to include some kind of research you may have done on web about this confusion of yours. And also, what exactly was the confusion you encountered in your day to day work or life. People will still be answering your questions but they will be more directed to the context you may have set in the question which in turn will help you! :)

Comment: @Mohit Thanks man. It is actually not a confusion of mine, but many friends have asked me about it. I just wanted to post the question for future reference to others.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Either* means any one of two possibilities, whereas *neither* means none of them.

For example:

> John: Would you like something to drink?
>   Jane: Either Coke or Pepsi would be fine.

Here, Jane would like something to drink—specifically, John can get her a Coke or a Pepsi. Generally, *either* excludes both options—John should **not** get her both a Coke and a Pepsi.

However, if the conversation were to go along these lines:

> John: Would you like coffee or tea?
>   Jane: Neither, thanks.

Here, Jane does not want any of the two options offered her—she does not want coffee, and she does not want tea.

Both *either* and *neither* should only be used when there are **two** options. If there are three or more, analogous words would be *any* and *none*.

Comment: Not quite. 1) *Either .. or* may be inclusive or exclusive (OR or XOR). 2) Both *either* and *neither* may be used with more than two options; think for instance of the US Postal Service creed: "Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds." However, **bare** *either* or *neither*, without further specification, should only be used of two options.

Answer (score 4):

*Either* usually means one, but not both (xor), whereas *neither* usually means none.

"Either `a`, `b`, or `c`" usually means "one of `a`, `b`, or `c`, but not more than one.

"Neither `a` nor `b`" usually means "not `a`, and not `b`".

Comment: Not so. English *or* may mean either OR or XOR.

Comment: @StoneyB Of course it _may_, but not usually in this context.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither:** Not any of those.

**Either:** Any of them.

For example:

> Would you like a Pepsi or a Coke?

When you respond with *either*, you mean that you'd have any of those. On the contrary, when you respond with *neither*, you mean that you wouldn't like to have any of those.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Either is used for Affirmation and Neither is used for Negation
For eg:-
 
1) We can either go to beach or to the hillstation
2) We can neither go the beach nor to the hillstation