# either vs neither

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Can someone please tell me which sentence is correct ?

- no action has been observed either from A or from B.
- no action has been observed neither from A nor from B.

If you believe that there is a better way of saying that, feel free to say it !

Thanks.

Comment: Which do you believe to be correct? What is your understanding of when to use either and when to use neither?

Comment: I am trying to say that they did not do anything.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Can someone please tell me which sentence is correct ?`

First, it depends on what are you trying to say. If you are trying to say that both A and B has done nothing then both sentence means the same. But, there is a difference which is listed below -:

> *no action has been observed either from A or from B.*
>
> > This sentence means A or B has done nothing.
>
> *no action has been observed neither from A nor from B.*
>
> > This sentence also means that *A or B has done nothing*. But, here some work was expected from both A and B.

The actual difference is made from the first word of the *second* sentence "no".

Moreover, i believe it's one of the best way of making these types of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You could say it as "No action has been observed from either A or B", "No action has been observed from neither A or B" or even "No action has been observed from either A or from B", but there are many ways to do this and both your examples make sense. Mainly about personal preference.