# Question about use of me too and me either

Tags: conjunctions, negation

What is the difference:

> -I want to drink something.
>
> -Me too.

And

> -I want to drink something.
>
> -Me either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "me neither" and "me either"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either) (*Me either* is at the very least "uncommon", and I would say it's "non-standard, incorrect".) And *Me neither* is wrong in this context, because it's a "negative polarity" item, which doesn't work when you ***do*** want something (as opposed to agreeing with someone that you ***don't*** want it).

Comment: *Me either* is extremely common.  It's just dialectal.

Comment: @snailboat -  I'm wondering if you could also tell me the difference between me either and me too and what us dialectal?

Comment: *Me either* is used in many American dialects in the same meaning as *me neither*.  The *either* version is rather more common here.  But some AmE speakers and all(?) BrE speakers think *me neither* is the right way to say it, so it's probably safer for a learner to use *me neither*. (For some reason, people take this dialect difference very seriously!)

Comment: Useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74390/agreeing-with-negative-sentences-me-neither-or-me-too/74393#74393

Answer (score 2):

The first conversation is grammatically correct. It means that person A wants to drink something. Person B agrees and also wants to drink something.

Your second conversation is incorrect though. 'Me either' is not a valid form in English. The following would be correct if you **didn't** want to drink something:

> -I don't want to drink something
>
> -Me neither