# "I have no question"--> "Me, too" or "Me, either"?

Tags: conjunctions, responses

Ok, at the end of an English class, the teacher says "*Do you have any questions?*"

> Student A:  I have no question
>
> Student B:  Me, too / Me, either

So, the Student B should say "*Me, too*" or "*Me, either*"?

I know that "Me, either" is American English: "*Me, either*" is American English: [Dictionary Link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/either_2).

**EDIT** (after comments): So, we can't use "Me, too" in this case?

Note: my question is unique. I know the rule of using "*Me, too*" or "*Me, either*". "*Me, too*" for positive sentence & "*Me, either*" for negative sentence.

> Ex: I have a question. Me, too
>
> Ex2: I don't have a question. Me, either.

So if we say "*I have no question*" then  which one we should use "*Me, too*" or "*Me, either*"?

Comment: @NES, after reading the question you provided, I could not know "Me, too" & "Me, either" cos "I have no question" seems to have negative meaning--> thus need "Me, either"

Comment: What about "Me, neither"?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between "me neither" and "me either"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either)

Comment: Is that really what your English teacher asked? Better ways to phrase that question would be: _Do you have any **questions**?_ or, _Do you have **a** question?_ or, _Does anyone have a question?_ or even, _Any questions?_ The way you've worded it here sounds off.

Comment: @NES et al - I really don't see how the [question you've linked to](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/question-about-use-of-me-too-and-me-either) would answer this question. _Related?_ You bet. _Duplicate and already answered there?_ I don't think so.

Comment: *Me, either* may be a usage in AmE, but as the dictionary says, it is "informal." It is also probably *dialectal*. In both AmE and BrE the formal and standard response would be *Me, neither*, just as @J.R. has stated.

Comment: Rathony is not a native speaker and his answer contains many errors, as well as non-natural English. J.R.is a native speaker.

Comment: @Tom - "I have no question" is negative. If you add that to both of NES's linked questions, then that should give you your answer. I can understand that you need all 3 parts to get the answer though, hence why marking this as a duplicate might be a bit unfair.

Comment: You could also use "Neither do I".

Comment: @NES - That may be so, but I do think the part of Ranthony's answer that's in the yellow quote box has some merit.

Comment: Useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74390/agreeing-with-negative-sentences-me-neither-or-me-too/74393#74393

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very tricky, and I think this question deserves its own answer.

The best way for Student B to chime in really depends on how Student A answers the initial question:

> - Student A: I have no question.
>     Student B: Me, neither.
> - Student A: I don't have any questions.
>     Student B: Me, either.
> - Student A: No questions from me!
>     Student B: Me, either.
> - Student A: I have some questions.
>     Student B: Me, too.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out when it's better to use *Me, either* or *Me, neither*.

Comment: So, we can not use "*Me, too*" if someone says "*I have no question*" right?

Comment: Generally not. If someone was trying to sound VERY colloquial and borderline ungrammatical, they MIGHT be able to get away with it in some contexts. For example, two guys coming back from a fishing trip: _"I caught no fish."_ _"Me, too!"_ But this is an exception; as far as I know, we don't usually use "Me, too" for negative statements.

Comment: @J.R. - Not sure where your confusion lies. In your first three examples, Student A always gives a negative response, hence Student B should always say "Me neither" if they want to be grammatical. If they want to use an Am.Eng colloquialism they can use "Me either" in any of the three.

Comment: I tried to answer this here. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74390/agreeing-with-negative-sentences-me-neither-or-me-too/74393#74393

Comment: Responding "Me, neither" to "I have no question" does not sound logical to me. I don't see "I have no question" as a real negative sentence, I see as an affirmation of no/zero value, which in that case "Me too" looks more appropriate. See: [this answer on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67062/i-have-no-vs-i-dont-have/67085#67085).

Answer (score 2):

> Student A: I have no questions.
>
> Student B: Me, too/Me, either.

As the student B is reacting to a negative statement made by A, you can use Me, either or Me, neither in informal AE.  In BE, you say  "Me, neither".

You say "Me, too" if you are reacting to a positive statement as follows:

> Student A: I have a question.
>
> Student B: Me, too.

Comment: *Me neither* is probably a safer choice for learners.  Speakers who accept *me either* generally accept *me neither* as well, but the reverse is not true; speakers who accept *me neither* might not accept *me either*.

Comment: I would request the downvoter to explain the reason for his downvote so as to enlighten me.

Comment: My comment came with an upvote, not a downvote :-)

Comment: Snailboat, I know it's not you who downvoted; your first comments were in support of my answer.  BTW, thanks.