# "Me either" or "Me too" - what's the correct reply?

Tags: conversation, adverbials

My friend, she texted me ' I"m just glad no cougar or bear approached you.'
 And I said ' Yeah, Me either'

I mean 'Me too'
Is this correct reply..?

Comment: "Me too" is correct because you mean "I am glad too."

Comment: See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33544/27840

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I have no question"--> "Me, too" or "Me, either"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74231/i-have-no-question-me-too-or-me-either)

Answer (score 1):

You will walk on much safer ground if you use:

> Me **too**.

---

It is a lot more common to use use "**either**" in the negative form, "**neither**":

> I do not have money.
>
> Me **neither**.