# Agreeing with negative sentences - "Me neither" or "Me too"?

Tags: conjunctions, negation

How do we agree with a negative sentence?

What is the choice? 'me neither' or 'me too'?

Say,

> Andy:  I don't like my teacher.
>   Bob:   Me, neither.

**OR**

> Andy:  I don't like my teacher.
>   Bob:   Me, too.

Comment: But what is a negative sentence?

Comment: Examples are there @DamkerngT. If you have better words/phrase for that, please help change the title/body.

Comment: I don't think I really can fix it because the example in your question is specific, so you seem to mean a specific meaning of "negative sentence" when asking the question. But your answer tries to generalize that, and your "negative sentence" seems to have a wider range. And really, I don't know the answer. In other words, I don't know what would be the answers of all possible sentences (e.g., is there any sentence that both the replies "Me, too" and "Me, (n)either" are equally valid?) Is "You can dislike your teacher" a negative sentence? What about "You barely like her"? and so on.

Comment: I barely like her - is there 'not' word? I **also** gave this example. So, the answer would be 'me too' and not 'me neither'.  @DamkerngT.

Comment: And, what do *you* mean by negative sentence? I meant actually [this](http://www.englishgrammar.org/negative-sentences/) @DamkerngT.

Comment: I didn't talk about my "negative sentence" (and I probably won't until I've finished reading CGEL; unless, of course, I want to use the term loosely). Now, back to your question, your comment implies that "I barely like her" should only be answered with "'me too' and not 'me neither'". You might find it interesting to google for `"I barely * me too", "I barely * me neither", "I barely * me either", "I hardly * me too", "I hardly * me neither", "I hardly * me either"`, and so on.

Comment: We both *know* google results, don't we? Anyway, I found it useful as those questions are closed/duplicate. You are free to express your views in anyway. @DamkerngT.

Comment: I don't want to continue this further, but let me be clear about my first comment, in case you might misread my tone. I posted it as a thought-provoking comment so the reader (and you, too, of course) would pause and think if the choice of *too/either/neither* is directly related to the sentence being negative, and if it is, it's negative how? in what way? -- BTW, wouldn't it be easier to vote to reopen the existing question if you think it was unreasonably closed?

Comment: **To the close voters** -that question is about replying with 'neither' and **'SO'**. This is about 'neither' and **TOO**. You mean 'so' and 'too' are equal? Furthermore, do they have the same *structure* in replying? Like - ***'So do I'*** equals ***'I too'***?

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, *barely* creates a negative context.  We can tell because negative polarity items work: *\*I like her **at all*** is ungrammatical because *at all* doesn't work in an affirmative context, but *I do**n't** like her **at all*** and *I **barely** like her **at all*** are both fine.  But *barely* doesn't contain an overt negator like *not*, so words like this are what Huddleston & Pullum call **covertly negative** (CGEL p.835).

Comment: But where does 'at all' come? @snailboat

Comment: *At all* is an example of a **negative polarity item** (NPI).  It's sensitive to whether the context it appears in is affirmative, negative, or interrogative.  Like most NPIs, it works only in negative and interrogative contexts, so we can use it as a test of sorts to see if a word creates a negative context.  This is relevant to the choice of *(n)either* and *too*: ① "I barely like her at all!"  "I do**n't either**." ② "I dislike my teacher." "I do, **too**."

Comment: @MaulikV Due to these "covertly negative" words like *barely*, the rule in your answer isn't quite right.  It's almost right – most negatives are "overt", which means they have an overt negator like *not* or *-n't* somewhere in them.  By the way, I see you've asked for references. I gave a page number for CGEL above, but I see from the comment in your answer that you have Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*.  He gives a very simplified version in section 367.5 "other negative words", where he writes: "Other words besides *not* can make a clause negative".  *Hardly* is one of his examples.

Comment: Yes, I don't have CGEL. Thanks for PEU's reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32500/discussion-between-snailboat-and-maulik-v).

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with negative sentences can take both - 'me neither' or 'me too'. But it depends on the negative sentence's construction.

If the negative sentence has 'not', reply it with 'neither' and not 'too'.

> I do not like my teacher ~ me neither *(not me too)*.

If the negative sentence does not contain 'not', reply it with 'me too' and not 'me neither'.

> I dislike my teacher ~ me too *(not me neither)*

---

I'm writing this as I see that [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74231/i-have-no-question-me-too-or-me-either) question is marked as a duplicate; **and furthermore** [the duplicate question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/question-about-use-of-me-too-and-me-either) is closed!

What is the source of this answer? I'm *not sure* because I found this from my English Notes. And my notes are straight from authentic sources like Oxford, Cambridge, Swan's PEU, Ed Swick etc.

If this sounds incorrect, I welcome comments preferably with *references*.

Comment: Well, problem is that *dislike* does not give a grammatically or semantically negative sentence. And more problematic loads of other words apart from *not* do give negative polarity sentences wich may therefore take *neither* instead of *too*. For example A: *I hardly ever go there* B: *Me neither*.

Comment: The whole issue is just with the word 'negative'. The solution is let's find how to put it in a right way. I'm pretty sure about my notes that come from authentic sources. And, I thought that since those both questions are closed, this would benefit others. @Araucaria

Comment: The thing is that you're generalizing. None of what you've written is wrong. Nevertheless, when you're writing in terms of generalizing what happens in language, your analysis has to be as complete as possible; otherwise, it's considered a flawed analysis. Hence why writing canonical posts is as cumbersome as it is.

Comment: The *only* flaw I find here is *no reference* I remember because it's **not** written in my notebook *(and I have many grammar books)*. It has **definitely** come from any of those *authentic* sources mentioned. And, when I write notes, I **don't change** my words as far as possible. Said that, those all *were* called 'negative sentences'. Downvoters *don't make* any difference to the facts. Even if it is *grayed*, it'll still serve the purpose. @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ.

Comment: @Maulik please reread my previous comment. I see nothing in this answer that is wrong. It's just that, trying to be a representative of the language, it's incomplete. And **it's wrong to do an incomplete analysis of language**. So either I'm not voting, or I'll up vote if you try to speak of the very sentence mentioned in your question, i.e. the specific case. The fact that what you've written is from authentic sources has nothing to do with the comprehensiveness of your analysis.