# A question about use of "too" in negative form

Tags: negation, adverb-placement

Is "too" able to be used in a negative sentence?

Let's see below.

Alice: I didn't like the movie.
Tom: I didn't like it, too.

Is the above correct?
The dictionary tells me that use of "either" is recommended there, but it does not say the use of "too" there is right or wrong.

How about below?

Alice: I didn't like the movie.
Tom: Me, too.

Any explanations about this matter will be so helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the negative, using "too" is wrong.  It can only be used with the positive.  Typically you should use 'neither', although in conversation it is acceptable to use 'either' as well.  For more info see:

[What is the difference between "me neither" and "me either"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either/33549)

Comment: But I can imagine somebody saying "Me too" as well as the more normal "Me neither".

Comment: To my ear as a native AmE speaker, if I said "I didn't like the movie" and someone said to me "Me too", it would absolutely sound wrong.  The only way I could make it sound right off the top of my head is with the response "I too was not a fan" if someone was trying to sound archaic.

Comment: I've heard "I didn't like it too" now and then. Not from adult speakers , however.   Teens and younger, where emphatic **too** is a kind of bonding experience.

Comment: I suppose I've heard it from kids, but it definitely sounds ungrammatical when I say it out loud.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you for the comment. May I ask you to explain a bit more about "a kind of bonding experience" you mentioned? I am not a native English speaker and can not understand at all what it means.

Comment: @Smart Humanism The speakers are emphasizing what they have in common with the other person with **too** as in "me too" which means "the same goes for me".