# Saying "You neither" as a response

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I want to know if it's correct to say "you neither"  in the context below

This is an informal conversation between "A" and "B"

> A: You didn't wake up early.
>
> B: **You neither** (meaning B is saying that A didn't wake up early)

I know B can say to A “Neither did you" or "You didn't wake up early either"

My question is can B say to A "You neither” (or “You either”) in that context that B is telling A that A also didn't wake up early?

I've never heard "you neither" as a response, and I want to know if it's grammatically correct to say "You neither" as response instead of "neither did you" or "you didn't wake up early either” in a context like the one above.

Comment: Debates? But the examples shown in this answer are very similar to yours https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "me neither" and "me either"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either)

Comment: @RubioRic I think this question is mainly focused on "you" part not the either or neither which is the case in the post you flagged as the duplicate. I don't think this is a duplicate, correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: @Cardinal It actually does make this question interesting. "Me neither" is common in colloquial speech. "You neither" sounds off (either nonidiomatic or low-register) to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is something of an oddity in English. "Me neither" is a common colloquialism (see the answer @RubioRic pointed out: [What is the difference between "me neither" and "me either"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/what-is-the-difference-between-me-neither-and-me-either)) However, "you neither" is not!

It's possible that it is used colloquially in some dialects that I'm unaware of, but for me, when I try to imagine hearing the following exchange:

> You didn't wake up early.
> You neither!

I can only picture "you neither" being spoken by a toddler who hasn't quite mastered the language yet.

Comment: First of all thank you for answering my question. To use  "me neither" as a response in an informal speech is common and acceptable but "you/he/she/they/we neither", or "John,Mary, Peter neither"  is odd and English native speakers would get thrown off and wouldn't understand it?

Comment: @user54219 Yes, I think that's mostly true. I think English speakers would "understand" it, but it would sound very odd. Also, "him/her/them/us" would be _slightly_ more appropriate than he/she/they/we, but would still sound wrong.